# MySQL select query return unrelated output

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT updateDate, id,cSsn,cLname,cFname,cDOB,cDOD,cCity,cState,cHospital,cCurstatus,cMmrcashworker,cTelephone FROM med_patient WHERE cCurstatus!='completed' AND cMmrcashworker = '2' AND cHospital = '1234' OR cHospital1 = '1234' OR cHospital2 ='1234' AND updateDate between '1/30/2010' and '1/28/2010' order by id desc'
```

Output:

```
updateDate   cHospital   cHospital1     cHospital2

01/15/2010   1234

01/15/2010   1234
```

But acutally to my knowledge my query must return an empty row.

Where is the mistake in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding some parentheses to your cHospital condition, otherwise the or will not be what you expect:

```
cCurstatus!='completed' AND cMmrcashworker = '2' AND
(cHospital = '1234' OR cHospital1 = '1234' OR cHospital2 ='1234') AND
updateDate between '1/30/2010' and '1/28/2010' order by id desc'
```

also:

```
... updateDate between '1/30/2010' and '1/28/2010' ...
```

^ that is doing a string compare rather than a date comparison, try changing to:

```
... updateDate between '2010-01-30' and '2010-01-28' ...
```

Comment: in my database table , am maintaining like 1/30/2010 , is it must i have to change the format.. else is there any alternate solution for my problem..

Comment: your db has values like '01/15/2010', so you will need to compare based on mm/dd/yyyy, which could be done as a string or date

Comment: <pre>
SELECT updateDate,cHospital,cHospital1,cHospital2 FROM med_patient WHERE cCurstatus!='completed' AND cMmrcashworker = '2' AND
(cHospital = '1234' OR cHospital1 = '1234' OR cHospital2 ='1234') AND
updateDate between '2010-01-1' and '2010-01-28' order by id desc
</pre>

As per your guidence , i have changed dateformat to 2010-01-28 ,


I have one patient entry, one of my patient updateDate is 2010-01-17 ,  but my above query return empty row , 

Why ?

Comment: one thing i want to convey , as per my database design my updateDate datatype is varchar ,

Comment: check the other values to see if they match... if you're changing your column type, probably best to make it a datetime (also '2010-01-1' looks like a typo, should be '2010-01-01')

Comment: i have changed my field to date format, but still it return only empty row as output

Comment: Am not sure, but after  i have changed to datetime format, i got expected result, now am going to different scenario testing with this query, thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

My problem is fixed. As per jspcal's guidance, I changed my datetype to datetime.

Now I get the expected output.